# What is the general formula for $\# \{ 1 \leq a \leq q-2,| (a,q)=1, (a+2,q)=1 \}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, congruences

Let $q=\prod P_i^{k_i}.$
I have learned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260257/sum-of-sum-substack1aq-a-q1-a1-q11) that $\# \{ 1 \leq a \leq q-1| (a,q)=1, (a+1,q)=1 \}= F(q)=\prod (p_i-2)pi^{k_i-1}
= q\prod (1-2/p_i)$

Here was the idea behind it :  For any $p_i$, there exists $p_i-2$ admissible reminders modulo $p_i$ (we exclude 0 and -1) thus $(p_i-2)p_i^{k_i-1}$ reminders modulo $p_i^{k_i}$. We get $F(q)$ by applying the Chinese Reminder Theorem.

I am now trying to find what would happen if instead of (a,q)=1 and (a+1,q)=1, we would have $(a,q)=1$ and $(a+2,q)=1$?  (with $ 1\leq a+2 \leq q$)

I want to find : 
$\# \{ 1 \leq a \leq q-2| (a,q)=1, (a+2,q)=1 \}$

I dont know if we could apply the same principle.  We would still have $(p_i-2)$ reminders modulo $p_i$. I am not quite sure.

Comment: This one *is* messy, if you are not prepared to "wrap around" and allow $a<q$ with $a+n>q$. If you allow wraparounds then the same proof works if $gcd(n,q)=1$. But if some prime divides both $n$ and $q$ you have to change the Euler factor at that prime.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot "wrap around". Could you give me an example of how it would work for, say,  (a,q)=1 and (a+2,q)=1?

Comment: @KevinBuzzard I dont "actually" need to find a formula for an arbitrary "n". However, I do have to compute it for a+2 and a+3. I would like to have a general idea of how it works.

Comment: Edited my question. Maybe its easier this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $q=\prod_ip_i^{k_i}$ is odd,
$$\# \{ 1 \leq a \leq q-2\, \vert \, (a,q)=1, (a+2,q)=1 \}
=-1+q\prod_i\left(1-\frac2{p_i}\right),$$
because the only number you miss (compared to your former problem) is $q-1$ which satisfies $(q-1,q)=1$ and $(q-1+2,q)=1$.

If $q$ is even, then
$$\# \{ 1 \leq a \leq q-2\, \vert \, (a,q)=1, (a+2,q)=1 \}
=-1+\frac{q}2\prod_{p_i\neq 2}\left(1-\frac2{p_i}\right).$$
Argue similarly.

Comment: How do you know this is the result?   What steps did you take to get these results?

Comment: You just use the Chinese Remainder theorem like in your previous question. Maybe ask on math.stackexchange if you need more hints?